# C# How to keep the DirectShow filter graph running on video window resize, minimize, device lost, reset?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, directshow.net, h.265

Our app is using C#/WinForms/VMR9/DirectShowLib-2005 to either play back a local video file or to receive (and render) the live video stream via udp using a third party DirectShow filter. The video stream uses H.265 coding and sends 1080p files.

I also have that DirectShow filter recording the live video feed to a local file for me.

When I resize the form during video playback or live video feed playback, I'm getting a device lost and need to reset it. I'm freeing all the resources, but device reset still fails unless I also destroy the graph as well. But it's used to receive my live video feed and record it.

So, problem is I would like to keep the video feed recorded without interruption by resize, move to another monitor, device lost or reset. What are my options to achieve this? We can consider converting the code to WPF/WF, purchasing a commercially available or using a free plugin to do the job, etc. Need an advice here.

Second question on the same subject, if I may. While live feed is recorded to a local file and we're playing back that live feed in the video window, we also display a time line (slider control), representing the time from the beginning of the live video feed till a present moment (which moves forward while the live feed is active). I need to give user the ability to select any previous moment in time and immediately play that part of the recorded video back, while live feed is still recorded to the same file. After reviewing a part of the recorded video, I need to know how to let user to continue watching the live feed.

I am not sure which technology we should be using to achieve that as well. I would appreciate any help.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Recording filter graphs are sensitive to unexpected state transitions and it is the assumption that recording takes place "at once" without pausing and continuations, including such as caused by necessity to reset video hardware or change format.

The typical method is to separate recording from other activity into separate graph. A dedicated recording graph would receive data produced outside and record it into file (or stream to network). Playback and presentation activity running in another graph can be flexibly reset or reconfigured as needed.

See also:

- [Directshow Preview Only and Capture & Preview with a single Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12001026/868014)